# how i can extract object fom json and convert that data into attribute in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, minify

i have used invoked http processor for get the alarm from web app. then i have to used split processor to spilt one alarm in one flow file. and the i have used evaluatejsonpath processor of extract data into attribute after that i want to used extract value in next http invoked processor for further used

---

problem is i didn't get the attribute form evaluatejsonpath processor if i select flowfile-content then i will get the id value and if i select flowfile-attribute i will not getting any attribute and value ...

Comment: evaluatejsonpath with flowfile-attribute should work. show a flow file example and the parameters of evaluatejsonpath, so, somebody could help you.

Answer (score 2):

@AnnapurnaGautam You need to set EvaluateJson to flowfile-attribute. Then you can use attribute ${id} in InvokeHTTP Remote Url.   You only use flowfile-content when you need the values in the body (flow file) for invokeHttp.

Please see my response in Cloudera Community with a template and the syntax for evaluateJsonPath to get ${id}.

```
$.history[0].id
```

Comment: thnksx for reply ...i have applied which you suggest ....but i m not getting result if i removed splitjson processor and use only http invoked for getting alarm and evaluatejsonpath for id ....it not giving any result ...i have used flowfile-attribute ..

Comment: you still have to use splitJson....   either that or json reader which will break it up into separate flowflies....  Go look at my full reply in Cloudera Community and my template...